# how do I select from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to work with EF, for the first time ever. I'm not sure I fully understand EF yet.

I already have a database with data in it, so I've generated my models from DB.
Our current setup runs EVERYTHING through stored procedures, even selects.
However, unless I'm mistaking, the models select directly into the tables, when I have generated them.

Can I change this behaviour, so it calls the select procedure instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - at least with EF4. I can't speak for EF5

You can use stored procedures to insert and update, but those stored procedures must have all the parameters EF expects, so you're probably going to have to wrap your existing procedures in new procedures.

For select, you can use a `FunctionImport` and `ExecuteFunction` to populate an Entity.